# Reading a sequence of HEX value (2 at a time) using fscanf in C

Tags: c, hex, scanf

So I have a text file, assume called text.txt. Its format is: `4C 4D 4E 4F` (i.e the hex values for the character string "LMNO"). I have correctly opened the text file, etc. How should I use `fscanf` to read the sequence of four bytes (i.e 1 byte at a time), storing each byte in a variable (with its appropriate data type). My end goal is to understand how to store in a character array `char test[4];` the letters `LMNO` (i.e test[0] = 'L', test[1] = 'M',...)

Comment: Use `%x` and put the `fscanf` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Call [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) in a loop while it returns `1`. With the correct format and arguments of course.

Comment: if I use one %x only wouldn't it store in each single HEX value (i.e 8 of them), instead I wanted to store 4C in one variable, 4D in another, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    char test[5] = {0};
    unsigned hex;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 4; ++i){
        if(1==fscanf(fp, "%2x", &hex))
            test[i] = (char)hex;
        else
            break;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    puts(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In line 6 you wrote `unsigned hex;`. Was that a typo, or is it correct?

Comment: @user3501476 not typo. `%x` requests the `unsigned*`. also `unsigned` and `unsigned int` is the same meaning.